# Fixing TypeError: sorted expected 1 argument, got 3

Tags: python, list, sorting, error-handling, typeerror

How can I fix this code so that it checks if the numbers in (a, b, c) are sorted and if not, it returns a Value Error as seen above?

```
def are_sorted(a, b, c):

    if sorted(a, b, c) != (a, b, c):
     raise ValueError("Must be ascending.")
    else:
      return [a, b, c]

print(are_sorted(1.6, 3.1, 2.7))
print(are_sorted(-2.3, 12.7, 28))
```

Right now it returns an error reading:

> TypeError: sorted expected 1 argument, got 3
> on line 3.

What's the easiest way to fix this issue on line 3?

Comment: sorted([1,2,3])

Comment: The easiest way is (1) read the documentation (2) do what it says.  You can sort *one* sequence -- an iterable with a well-defined less-than relation -- not an arbitrary series of individual values.  Wrap `em in brackets and call it done.

Comment: Note that you could just write `if a <= b <= c:` instead of calling `sorted`.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need `*args`.
https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/

`sorted` takes 1 argument. `,` separates arguments, so python thinks you are passing three args. Instead, you can pass in an iterable such as a tuple or list. `*args` will be your friend here.

```
def are_sorted(*args):
    print(args)
    if sorted(args) != args:
     raise ValueError("Must be ascending.")
    else:
      return args


print(are_sorted(10,5,2))
```

output

```
(10, 5, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 9, in <module>
File "<string>", line 4, in are_sorted
ValueError: Must be ascending.
```